QWC running configuration under WLS
I'am trying to configure QWC against my QGIS project. Using GWC Admin under docker under WLS. After fixing all project warnings when trying generete configuration a ended with this error. Is it about creating some directories or change privillegies but I can not find where. to do it.

Error while refreshing config cache:
Python Exception: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/srv/qwc_service/config-out/default/>adminGuiConfig.json'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/srv/qwc_service/./server.py", line 55, in generate_configs
generator.write_configs()
File "/srv/qwc_service/./config_generator/config_generator.py", line 346, in >write_configs
copyfile(
File "/usr/lib/python3.9/shutil.py", line 266, in copyfile
with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/srv/qwc_service/config-out/default/>adminGuiConfig.json'


I had the same error message and was able to fix it. Recently the documentation was revised and 4 important steps were removed.
In the old documentation
(https://github.com/qwc-services/qwc-docker/commit/8198850167b8912b546700361093ce054dec6f71#diff-b335630551682c19a781afebcf4d07bf978fb1f8ac04c6bf87428ed5106870f5)
the following steps are still performed:

Change the ownership of the writeable volumes accordingly:
sudo chown -R 33:33 volumes/attachments
sudo chown -R 33:33 volumes/config
sudo chown -R 33:33 volumes/qgs-resources
sudo chown -R 33:33 volumes/qwc2/assets



If you execute these afterwards and restart the server with “docker restart $(docker ps -q)” it should work.
Translated with DeepL.com (free version)
